# JTextField and getActionCommand to store in a user expanding array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, indexoutofboundsexception

My main purpose with this GUI program is to have the user enter the first name of a student into the first name box and the corresponding last name into the last name box and then hit save. Hitting Save will then save the first and last name into their respective arrays. After the user is done entering names they will then click sort. This will then sort the names in alphabetical order and then re-draw the GUI to show the result for the newly sorted array of names. My main problems I have is that when I enter a name I get a laundry list of errors (seen below.) I also do not know how to redraw the GUI to show the array of names in a list. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Here is my current code. (The variable names are long but I hate making variable names and then forgetting what they are used for.)
    import java.awt.*;

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class main extends JFrame {

    JTextField studentNameInputFirst, studentNameInputLast, studentNamesEnetered;
    JButton nextName, sort;
    JLabel firstName, lastName;
    String disp = "";
    int totalNumberOfStudents = 0;
    String[] studentFirstNames = new String[totalNumberOfStudents];
    String[] studentLastNames = new String[totalNumberOfStudents];

    public main() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        studentNamesEnetered = new JTextField();
        studentNameInputFirst = new JTextField(15);
        studentNameInputLast = new JTextField(15);
        nextName = new JButton("Save");
        sort = new JButton("Sort");
        firstName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
        lastName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");

        container.add(firstName);
        container.add(studentNameInputFirst);
        container.add(lastName);
        container.add(studentNameInputLast);
        container.add(nextName);
        container.add(sort);

        nextName.addActionListener(new nextNameListener());
        sort.addActionListener(new sortListener());

        setSize(325, 120);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class nextNameListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            totalNumberOfStudents++;
            studentFirstNames[totalNumberOfStudents] = studentNameInputFirst.getText();
            studentLastNames[totalNumberOfStudents] = studentNameInputLast.getText();
            studentNameInputLast = null;
            studentNameInputFirst = null;
        }
    }
    private class sortListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main drawGui = new main();
        drawGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Here is the error I get when running the above code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at main$nextNameListener.actionPerformed(main.java:48)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT: After using the answer provided suggesting an ArrayList instead of a normal array, I get no more errors. I made changes as well to the naming of my program to follow the Java naming conventions and for my own sanity of knowing what the program does. Changes were made on lines, 13, 14, 45, and 46. Thanks for your help!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ClassNameSorting extends JFrame {

    JTextField studentNameInputFirst, studentNameInputLast, studentNamesEnetered;
    JButton nextName, sort;
    JLabel firstName, lastName;
    String disp = "";
    ArrayList<String> studentNameFirst = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> studentNameLast = new ArrayList<String>();


    public ClassNameSorting() {
        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        studentNamesEnetered = new JTextField();
        studentNameInputFirst = new JTextField(15);
        studentNameInputLast = new JTextField(15);
        nextName = new JButton("Save");
        sort = new JButton("Sort");
        firstName = new JLabel("First Name: ");
        lastName = new JLabel("Last Name: ");

        container.add(firstName);
        container.add(studentNameInputFirst);
        container.add(lastName);
        container.add(studentNameInputLast);
        container.add(nextName);
        container.add(sort);

        nextName.addActionListener(new nextNameListener());
        sort.addActionListener(new sortListener());

        setSize(325, 120);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class nextNameListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            studentNameFirst.add(studentNameInputFirst.getText());
            studentNameLast.add(studentNameInputLast.getText());
            studentNameInputLast = null;
            studentNameInputFirst = null;
        }
    }
    private class sortListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassNameSorting drawGui = new ClassNameSorting();
        drawGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've gotten a decent answer to this question, however in the future please show us which line causes any exceptions that you're asking about. For instance, here your stacktrace is telling you that the exception is being thrown on line: 48 -- (`(main.java:48)`). Also, you'll want to make sure that your code complies with Java naming standards meaning class names should begin with an upper case letter. This helps others (us!) understand your code much more quickly.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Java is somewhat new to me (I ended up being put in an Advanced Java class in college even though I had no prior Java knowledge) I will remember the naming convention for now on! I as well have made the changes suggested in the answer and I do not get anymore errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int totalNumberOfStudents = 0;
String[] studentFirstNames = new String[totalNumberOfStudents];
String[] studentLastNames = new String[totalNumberOfStudents];
```

Your array size is 0. You need to allocate the array with then number of entries you expect to add to the array.

Don't use an Array because you don't know what the size should be. Instead use an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thanks I have changed to an ArrayList. I have added my edited code to my post under my Edit. Thanks again!